# In karate I am trying to find a key from API Json response and key looks like "payment:canel" but getting Error

Tags: json, api, karate

I am trying to find a key from API Json response and key looks like "payment:canel" but when I try to find the json path using **Response.somekey.payment:cancel** karate throws java script evaluation error

The response looks like:

```
{
    "Outcome": "SUCCESS",

    "_links": {
        "payment:cancel": {
            "href": "http://myhost:8080/12345"
        }

    }
}
```

I tried with below:

```
* def a = Response._links.payments:cancel.href
```